# Using bootstrap datepicker in steps: year -> month -> day

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I am using the bootstrap datepicker for a Date of Birth field. 
But apparently users are not using the year drop down field properly.

What I would like to do is have a staged setup, where with 3 clicks they go from choosing year, then month and then the day. I think it would be much more user friendly. 
This is how i see it working:

**step 1: select year**

[image]

**Step 2: select month**

[image]

**step 3: select day**

[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? Can you link it?

Comment: I am actually using the jQuery UI [https://jqueryui.com/datepicker], but happy to use the bootstrap one too (pictured above) [https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/]

Comment: Actually now i see that the bootstrap version has something called 'view mode', which when set to years seems to be what i am looking for. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check this
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

you can change mode like below,

```js
jQuery(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years'
            });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```